# Why would fetch return "TypeError: Failed to fetch" and not just "Failed to fetch"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am running this code and testing with no internet connection:

```
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => {
    // irrelevant, as catch happens immediately on no network connection
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Failed fetch ', err);
  });
```

What does the 'TypeError' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you snippet, it should log

```
Failed fetch TypeError: ...
```

and `TypeError` are throw when fetch not success

more information please check

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError

Answer (score 0):

A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered.

plus,the first then get a resolved promise object.You should use then after like this:

```js
fetch(url, options)
  .then(res =>res.json())
  .then(data=>{console.log('data from server',JSON.stringify(data))})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Failed fetch ', err);
  });
```

[Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)